# From dataframe create dict with tuple of multiple columns as key and another column as value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
Sr. |  From  | Tran type | Inv type |  Opposite   |    Comment   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
6   | Seller |    X, Y   |   P, Q   |    Buyer    | Rand comment |
```

**Where 'Sr.' is the index of the df.** There are several rows in the df, and varying number of values in 'Tran type' and 'Inv type' columns of each row.

I want to create a dict list this:

```
{k:v} = {(From, Tran type, Inv type, To) : Comment}
```

The keys are essentially cross products of the 4 columns, and each key will only contain one value of Tran type and Inv type. For the above example, it should look like this:

```
{
 (Seller, X, P, Buyer): Rand Comment,
 (Seller, X, Q, Buyer): Rand Comment,
 (Seller, Y, P, Buyer): Rand Comment,
 (Seller, Y, Q, Buyer): Rand Comment
}
```

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
def create_combos_dict(rule):
    tran_types = str(rule['Tran type'])
    tran_types = tran_types.split()
    inv_types = str(rule['Inv type'])
    inv_types = inv_types.split()
    from_side = str(rule['From'])
    opposite = str(rule['Opposite'])
    
    key_tuple = product([from_side], tran_types, inv_types, [opposite])
    combos_dict = {combo:str(rule['Comment']) for combo in key_tuple}
    return combos_dict

mapped_dict = {}
mapped_dict.update(df.apply(create_combos_dict, axis=1))
mapped_dict
```

However, this is the output I get:

```
{6: {
        (Seller, X, P, Buyer): Rand Comment,
        (Seller, X, Q, Buyer): Rand Comment,
        (Seller, Y, P, Buyer): Rand Comment,
        (Seller, Y, Q, Buyer): Rand Comment
    }
}
```

Why is the dict forming with 'Sr.' as key and the value is actual dict I'm making?

For the time being, I'm iterating through `combos_dict.values()` and adding those to another dict. But surely there has to be some simple fix to this?

Comment: Could you share a sample of your dataframe? I think I would try first to adjust the dataframe to a better format (having columns like `(Seller, X, P, Buyer)` )and then generate the dictionary.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, it's on my company VDI and I can't paste that here. However, I don't think it's practical for me to make the columns the way you have suggested, as it would be manually doing the task I'm trying to automate. The df hold possible values for each variable and I need to check if data I receive is of one of those possible combinations, which is why I'm creating a cross product dict since my dataset and df are massive and vary a lot in terms of said combinations

Answer (score 0):

What I was meaning was the following:

```
import functools as ft
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[6,"Seller","X, Y","P, Q","Buyer","Rand comment"],
                  [6,"Seller","Z, Y","L, Q","Buyer","Rand comment"]],
                  columns = ["Sr.","From","Tran type","Inv type","Opposite","Comment"])

df[["col1","col2"]] = df["Tran type"].str.split(",", expand = True,)
df[["col3","col4"]] = df["Inv type"].str.split(",", expand = True,)
df["col5"] = df.apply(lambda x: {(x["From"],x["col1"],x["col3"],x["Opposite"]):x["Comment"],
                                (x["From"],x["col1"],x["col4"],x["Opposite"]):x["Comment"],
                                (x["From"],x["col2"],x["col3"],x["Opposite"]):x["Comment"],
                                (x["From"],x["col2"],x["col4"],x["Opposite"]):x["Comment"]},axis = 1)

ft.reduce(lambda total,x: {**total,**x},df["col5"])
```

Output:

```
{('Seller', 'X', 'P', 'Buyer'): 'Rand comment',
 ('Seller', 'X', ' Q', 'Buyer'): 'Rand comment',
 ('Seller', ' Y', 'P', 'Buyer'): 'Rand comment',
 ('Seller', ' Y', ' Q', 'Buyer'): 'Rand comment',
 ('Seller', 'Z', 'L', 'Buyer'): 'Rand comment',
 ('Seller', 'Z', ' Q', 'Buyer'): 'Rand comment',
 ('Seller', ' Y', 'L', 'Buyer'): 'Rand comment'}
```